Is it possible to get less camera latency using OpenCV?
I'm learning python and i'm working with OpenCV.
My goal is :
When I execute my python script : it starts recording a 10 seconds sequence with my USB webcam which is a Logitech C920 and the video is writed on my desktop.
I did it ! However, my camera take 1 minutes and 8 seconds to start recording : that's so long. I would like to start maximum 3 seconds after executing the script.
My code :
import cv2
import os
import time

desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
video_filename = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'video_output.mp4')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
fps = 30  # Frames per second

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_filename, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

start_time = time.time()
while int(time.time() - start_time) < 10:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        # Écrire le cadre dans le fichier vidéo
        out.write(frame)

        # Afficher la vidéo en cours de capture (optionnel)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        # Arrêter si l'utilisateur appuie sur 'q'
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(f"Vidéo enregistrée sous : {video_filename}")


Someone have an idea to correct this camera latency ?
Ty for reading
I tried to use my PC webcam and it take less time. (only 7 seconds to record).

You are on Windows. Try the CAP_DSHOW and CAP_MSMF modes to VideoCapture. That usually makes the difference.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_MSMF)

